# Render React element from object value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to create an object:

```
import React from "react";
import { Registration } from "../../";

const RouteObj = {
  Registration: {
    route: "/registration",
    comp: <Registration />
  }
};
export default RouteObj;
```

And then, in a second file call:

```
import React from 'react';
import RouteObj from ...

class Thing extends React.Component{
  render() {
    <RouteObj.Registration.comp />
  }
}
```

When trying this, I get the error:

> React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in.

Is it possible to render React components in this way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Registration` is already a tag (a component), that's why I guess you have to use curly brackets instead.

```
import React from 'react';
import RouteObj from ...

class Thing extends React.Component{
  render() {
    <div>
      {RouteObj.Registration.comp}
    </div>
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to pass props to the RouteObj.Registration.comp component?

Comment: @SummmerFort Yes, you can use `cloneElement` function. `React.cloneElement(RouteObj.Registration.comp, props)`. `props` is an object with your props.

Answer (score 1):

1. You've got to export `RouteObj` correctly, as the default export.

Thus, add this after you declare `RouteObj`:

```
export default RouteObj;
```

You were trying to use something you didn't export, as the error says. It was thus undefined.

2. You can't create an element *from an element*, you need to create an element from a *component class*. So instead, you have to set `RouteObj.comp` to `Registration`, the component class itself, not an instance of `Registration`, `<Registration  />`.

So, instead, this is what `comp` should be:

```
comp: Registration
```

Comment: Sorry, I will edit the code, I am exporting it correctly. Wrapping {RouteObj.Registration.comp} works as above!